# Regex Replace A Variable Within Brackets, Including Brackets

Tags: regex, variables, square-bracket

How do I get rid of a variable within square brackets, including the brackets themselves? E.g. [152] or [153] or [154]. I am using Yahoo Pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the brackets (like any other character with a special meaning) with `\`.

```
s/\[\d+\]/Replacement/
```

In Yahoo Pipes it should work like: *replace* `\[.+\]` *with* `(leave blank)`. Maybe you have to check the `g` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if the variables will always be numbers my solutions works by removing all occurrences of [anything]

replace

```
\[[^\]]*\] with ""
```

javascript example

```
var s = "[152] xxx [153]zzz [154] i";

s = s.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/g,'') 

s ; //# =>  xxx zzz  i
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var rx= '/[\[\.*\]]/g';    
var s = "[152]  [153] [154] ";
s.replace(rx,'');
```

### [DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/dg9ULJoeGR)